# Text inserted by js deletes when user interacts with page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've made Chrome Extension which on Upwork job page inserts text into textarea for Cover Letter. The problem now is when I press the гupwork page's button 'Send', the text deletes.
I will add screens to visualise the process and add the code which inserts the text.
If you have any ideas why it's happening, you'll do my day!

Screens:
[Button and text area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72M9f.png)

[After button "GetPrompt" is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEG4v.png)

[After button "Send" is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCUXI.png)

The code inserting text:

```
textArea = document.querySelector('.up-textarea');
textArea.value = GPT_reply;
```

Thank you!

I haven't tried other aproaches as I don't really know what it shoud be in this case